# Angular factory ajax call on every route change

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-services

I have a factory where I have a function getExpenseList which does an ajax call which queries the expense table and gives me the result.

Now I have two routes, 1 which is listing of expenses which is pushing the expense through the above function and the second route is an add. When I do a route change and come back to the listing page, the ajax call is made again. Ideally I should be able to store the expense object on the first ajax call and then reference the same object till someone is manually refreshing the browser.

please help me on this. Here is my factory code. Ideally I would like to refer to this.expenses if the data is present.

```
admin.factory('expenseFact', ['$http', function($http) {
    var expense = {};

    this.expenses = "";

    expense.getExpenseList = function() {
        this.expenses = $http({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            method: "GET",
            url: base_url + "rest/expenses"
        });

        return this.expenses;
    };

    return expense;
}]);
```

And here is my controller code

```
admin.controller('expenseLandCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope,expenseFact) {
    $scope.pageTitle = $rootScope.pageTitle;

    expenseFact.getExpenseList().then(function (data) {
        $scope.expenses = data.data;
    });

});

admin.controller('expenseAddCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope,expenseFact) {
    $scope.pageTitle = $rootScope.pageTitle;
});
```

Comment: i would suggest that you use module pattern and only call the getExpenseList when needed. in your factory its returning expense always and that's why it'll always get called because you're making it part of json object expense

Answer (score 0):

your factory will be like this

```
    admin.factory('expenseFact', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getExpenseList: function() {
            var expense = {};
            this.expenses = $http({
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                method: "GET",
                url: base_url + "rest/expenses"
            });

            return this.expenses;
        }
    }
}]);
```

and you can call it from controller same way and it wont call it automatically. 
btw i recommend use of promises.

below is same code with use of promise

```
admin.factory('expenseFact', ['$http', '$q'. function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getExpenseList: function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
                }).
            then(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }, function(response) {
                deferred.reject(response.status)
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: where is the url? I want to try the promise thing. But I am not sure where you are putting the url

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the expenses once when the factory is loaded for the first time;

```
admin.factory('expenseFact', ['$http', function($http) {
    var expenses = null;
    $http({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            method: "GET",
            url: base_url + "rest/expenses"
    }).success(function (exp) {
        expenses = exp;
    }); // get the expenses when the factory is loaded

    return {expenses: expenses};
}]);
```

What this does is that it makes the `expenses` return from the factory refer to the one-time ajax call to get the expenses.